# My HP chromebook will not stop making this loud chiming noise. How can I fix this?

Tags: audio, chromebook

My Chromebook is a Hp. I don't know what to do.

Comment: You need to give us some idea of what you are hearing.

Comment: A chime a very loud chime.

Comment: Like EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE that is the noise

Comment: Check your fan or hard drive. Boot to BIOS (no OS). Does it still make the noise.

Comment: OMG.. EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE is golden :^P

Comment: Simplify Please I not good with computers

Comment: Can you please go in more detail

Comment: Answer to help you provided here.

Comment: You are being asked to check the fans, or the component which is used to store data. There should be an option to boot to BIOS, so look it up as to how to boot to BIOS for a chromebook. (Also your description could have been better than just EEE)

Answer (score 0):

I think that more than likely your issue is the fan. Over time fans can become dysfunctional due to dust buildup. You should follow the fan guide listed on this site at HP Chromebook 14-Q010DX Fan Replacement to remove the fan and clean it. If this doesn't fix your problem you should consider replacing your fan with a new one, or maybe a short to the speaker. hope this solves your issue! ( if it is a school Chromebook, let your administrator know.

Answer (score 0):

Start your Chromebook in BIOS

[Start Chromebook in BIOS](https://www.howtogeek.com/279308/how-to-restore-your-chromebooks-original-bios-and-software/#:%7E:text=From%20within%20Chrome%20OS%2C%20press,to%20access%20a%20full%20shell.&text=When%20the%20script%20interface%20appears,%E2%80%9C4%E2%80%9D%20and%20pressing%20Enter.)

> From within Chrome OS, press Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal window.
> Type shell and press Enter to access a full shell. When the script
> interface appears, choose the “Set Boot Options (GBB Flags)” option by
> typing “4” and pressing Enter.

If the above process does not work, shut down, and then when you start up, right away press F2 repeatedly and that should start in BIOS.

Once it starts in BIOS, listen for the noise. The same noise will indicate it is the fan making the noise.

Almost for sure, you will need to get the machine serviced at a local repair shop. If someone else owns the chromebook, let them know before taking it to the repair shop.

Comment: It says it is not a command

Comment: Shut down, start up and right away press F2 repeatedly. That should get you into BIOS.